# Rails: Conditionally enable Rack::Deflater?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

We are moving to a newer version of API in our rails server and would like to enable the Deflater / gzip -compression, but only for the new api-routes.

routes.rb is similar to this:

```
....
....
def add_api_routes
  resources :foo, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :bar, only: [:index, :show]
end

namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' }, constraints: { subdomain: /internal|^$/ }, path: '/'  do
  namespace :v2, module: nil do
    add_api_routes
  end

  namespace :v1, module: nil do
    add_api_routes
  end
end
....
....
```

We did add the following line to application.rb

```
...
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
...
```

But this enables gzip for both the versions.

Is is possible to enable it only for one version of api. (for eg. v2) ?

Thanks. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the initializer seems to accept conditionals: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/deflater.rb#L31 Dig it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @apneadiving in his comment. From condition here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/deflater.rb#L31, you can do something like this:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater, :if => lambda { |env, status, headers, body| env["PATH_INFO"] == "/v2/" } # or Regular expression: env["PATH_INFO"].match(/\/v2\//) matches -> /v2/
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is exactly what we want. Let me try it out and will mark it the correct/accepted one.